# I want my Flutter app to automatically open when user hangs up a call

Tags: android, flutter

When a user receives a call and ends it. I want a small pop up from flutter app, which asks if the recent call was an enquiry or not. Once the user presses yes, it has to take him to the flutter app where he can enter rest of the details.

I can manage the rest of the app, but can someone give some pointers as to how I can do this. IOS is not a necessity. As long as it works with Android its fine.

Comment: It might be too broad If you ask for BOTH ios and Android, there is no that bullet to kill both platform-specific issue. And you miss the *Android* or *iOS* tag, flutter have no power to do this by its own.